# Run Ethereum Blockchain offline on Virtual Machines

Tags: blockchain

It is pleasure to be part of this community.

I am doing University project, which is aiming to use blockchain technology to host and store voting event and then evaluate the security and performance. 
The plan I am thinking of is to get Ethereum source code and run it on virtual machines then create an application to act as an user which is trying to vote. I have some basic coding knowledge but can you guys give me some information of where to start, which tools to use, is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

To run a local test version of Ethereum, use Ganache. http://truffleframework.com/ganache/

It will create you a running Ethereum blockchain and a few accounts out of the box, no config needed. It also tracks all transactions and creates logs. Very helpful indeed.

Caveat: at this precise moment in time, it is not *super* stable. But it should definitely serve the purposes of dev and testing!

Comment: Thank you too. I will be working on this during this week and will see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

running Ganache is fairly easy, another option is to run your own private ethereum blockchain with GETH

I did this same experiment on a VM  and wrote a post about it hope it would help
[building a private ethereum blockchain](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/building-ethereum-private-blockchain-m-heni-merzouki/)

Comment: Thanks alot I will give it a go this week and will keep you updated. Have a great day!